# Trying to make a discord logging bot with embeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
bot.on('messageDelete', function(message) {

    if(message.channel.type == 'text') {

        //log to console
        console.log('[' + message.guild.name + '][#' + message.channel.name + '][DELMSG] ' + message.author.username +
            '#' + message.author.discriminator + ': ' + formatConsoleMessage(message));

        //post in the guild's log channel
        var log = message.guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
        if (log != null)
            .setTitle("Message Deleted")
            .addField("Author", message.author.username)
            .addField("Message", message.cleanContent)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
            .setColor("0x00AAFF");
            log.sendEmbed(embed)
```

This is the code I have so far, but atm I'm having the problem "Expression expected" at ".setTitle" oor just at the first section of the embed. I have no clue what it wants me to put above it though.

Full Code:

```
/*
    Logger v0.1.0
    A bot for Discord that logs moderator actions.
    -----------------------------------------------
    Copyright © Richard Kriesman 2016.
*/

//imports

//constants
const VERSION = '0.1.1';
//const TOKEN = 'TOKEN GOES HERE';
const CHANNEL = 'log-town';

//declarations
//var bot = new Discord.Client();

//
// Event Handlers
//

//bot is ready to start working, print status update to console
bot.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('[META][INFO] Connected to Discord API Service');
});

//bot disconnected from Discord
bot.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log('[META][WARN] Disconnected from Discord API Service. Attempting to reconnected...');
});

//warning from Discord.js
bot.on('warn', function(msg) {
    console.log('[META][WARN] ' + msg);
});

//error from Discord.js
bot.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('[META][ERROR] ' + err.message);
    process.exit(1);
});

//message received
bot.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.author.id != bot.user.id) {
        if (message.channel.type == 'text')
            console.log('[' + message.guild.name + '][#' + message.channel.name + '][MSG] ' + message.author.username +
                '#' + message.author.discriminator + ': ' + formatConsoleMessage(message));
        else if (message.channel.type == 'dm')
            message.channel.sendMessage('Beep boop! Sorry, I can\'t respond to direct messages. Try inviting me to your ' +
                'server!\nhttps://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=643707791910895634&scope=bot&permissions=8');
        else if (message.channel.type == 'group')
            message.channel.sendMessage('Beep boop! Sorry, I can\'t log group messages. Try inviting me to your server!\n' +
                'https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=643707791910895634&scope=bot&permissions=8');
    }
});

//message deleted
client.on('messageDelete', message => {
    if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
      var logger = message.guild.channels.get(CHANNEL);
      if (logger) {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle('Message Deleted')
          .addField('Author', message.author.username)
          .addField('Message', message.cleanContent)
          .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
          .setColor('0x00AAFF');
        logger.send({ embed });
      }
    }
  });

                                        //log.sendMessage('**[Message Deleted]** ' + message.author + ': ' + message.cleanContent);



//message update
bot.on('messageUpdate', function(oldMessage, newMessage) {

    if (newMessage.channel.type == 'text' && newMessage.cleanContent != oldMessage.cleanContent) {

        //log to console
        console.log('[' + newMessage.guild.name + '][#' + newMessage.channel.name + '][UPDMSG] ' +
            newMessage.author.username + '#' + newMessage.author.discriminator + ':\n\tOLDMSG: ' +
            formatConsoleMessage(oldMessage) + '\n\tNEWMSG: ' + formatConsoleMessage(newMessage));

        //post in the guild's log channel
        var log = newMessage.guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
        if (log != null)
            log.sendMessage('**[Message Updated]** *' + newMessage.author + '*:\n*Old Message*: ' + oldMessage.cleanContent +
                '\n*New Message*: ' + newMessage.cleanContent);
    }

});

//user has been banned
bot.on('guildBanAdd', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][BAN] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null)
        log.sendMessage('**[Banned]** ' + user);

});

//user has been unbanned
bot.on('guildBanRemove', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UNBAN] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null)
        log.sendMessage('**[Unbanned]** ' + user);

});

//user has joined a guild
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][JOIN] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null) {
        log.sendMessage('**[Joined]** ' + user);
    }

});

//user has joined a guild
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', function(guild, user) {

    //log to console
    console.log('[' + guild.name + '][LEAVE] ' + user.username + '#' + user.discriminator);

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null)
        log.sendMessage('**[Left]** ' + user);

});

//user in a guild has been updated
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', function(guild, oldMember, newMember) {

    //declare changes
    var Changes = {
        unknown: 0,
        addedRole: 1,
        removedRole: 2,
        username: 3,
        nickname: 4,
        avatar: 5
    };
    var change = Changes.unknown;

    //check if roles were removed
    var removedRole = '';
    oldMember.roles.every(function(value) {
        if(newMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.removedRole;
            removedRole = value.name;
        }
    });

    //check if roles were added
    var addedRole = '';
    newMember.roles.every(function(value) {
        if(oldMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.addedRole;
            addedRole = value.name;
        }
    });

    //check if username changed
    if(newMember.user.username != oldMember.user.username)
        change = Changes.username;

    //check if nickname changed
    if(newMember.nickname != oldMember.nickname)
        change = Changes.nickname;

    //check if avatar changed
    if(newMember.user.avatarURL != oldMember.user.avatarURL)
        change = Changes.avatar;

    //log to console
    switch(change) {
        case Changes.unknown:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSR] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
        case Changes.addedRole:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][ADDROLE] ' + newMember.user.username +'#' +  newMember.user.discriminator +
                ': ' + addedRole);
            break;
        case Changes.removedRole:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][REMROLE] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator +
                ': ' + removedRole);
            break;
        case Changes.username:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSRNM] ' + oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator +
                ' is now ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
        case Changes.nickname:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSRNK] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator +
                (oldMember.nickname != null ? ' (' + oldMember.nickname + ')' : '') +
                (newMember.nickname != null ? ' is now ' + newMember.nickname : ' no longer has a nickname.'));
            break;
        case Changes.avatar:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDAVT] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
    }


    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null) {
        switch(change) {
            case Changes.unknown:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Update]** ' + newMember);
                break;
            case Changes.addedRole:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Role Added]** ' + newMember + ': ' + addedRole);
                break;
            case Changes.removedRole:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Role Removed]** ' + newMember + ': ' + removedRole);
                break;
            case Changes.username:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Username Changed]** ' + newMember + ': Username changed from ' +
                    oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator + ' to ' +
                    newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
                break;
            case Changes.nickname:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Nickname Changed]** ' + newMember + ': ' +
                    (oldMember.nickname != null ? 'Changed nickname from ' + oldMember.nickname +
                        + newMember.nickname : 'Set nickname') + ' to ' +
                    (newMember.nickname != null ? newMember.nickname + '.' : 'original username.'));
                break;
            case Changes.avatar:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Avatar Changed]** ' + newMember);
                break;
        }
    }

});

//
// Startup Sequence
//
console.log('Logger v' + VERSION);
console.log('A bot for Discord that logs moderator actions.\n');
console.log('Copyright © Richard Kriesman 2016. Released under the MIT license.');
console.log('----------------------------------------------');

console.log('[META][INFO] Started Logger v' + VERSION);

//bot.login(TOKEN); //log in to discord

function formatConsoleMessage(message) {
    return message.cleanContent.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'g'), '\n\t');
}
```

I've put in tthe full code because it differs from the original (https://github.com/richardkriesman/discord-logger/blob/master/server.js) a bit, but the main problem at the moment is the "message deleted" partt. I'm trying to make it send embed rather than a normal message.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here can you explain a bit more

Comment: please replace `var logger = message.guild.channels.get(CHANNEL);` with `var logger = message.guild.channels.find(
      channel => channel.name === CHANNEL
    );`

Comment: the find method is updated the code which you've copied from is old and deprecated.

Comment: Like this right?
`client.on('messageDelete', message => {
    const CHANNEL = 'log-town';
    if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
        var logger = message.guild.channels.find( channel => channel.name === CHANNEL );
        channel => channel.name === CHANNEL;`

It won't send to channel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have messed up a little with your code.

try this

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageDelete', message => {
  const CHANNEL = 'log';
  if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
    var logger = message.guild.channels.find(
      channel => channel.name === CHANNEL
    );
    if (logger) {
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Message Deleted')
        .addField('Author', message.author.username)
        .addField('Message', message.cleanContent)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor('0x00AAFF');
      logger.send({ embed });
    }
  }
});

client.login('YOUR TOKEN');
```

Updated the answer, so you need to have a log channel with every server, and whenever a user deletes a message the embed will be sent to log channel.

Comment: Whenever I do delete the message I get:
"TypeError: log.setTitle is not a function"

Comment: @PeppaPapa i am trying discord.js on my machine will give you solution in a bit

Comment: @PeppaPapa updated my work as per the docs of discord.js let me know if this works

Comment: It didn't crash it but it also didn't send the log.

In the code it will grab the channel for you, needed for multi server setup cus I'm stupid and don't know how I'dd do that. Here's the link to the original code: https://github.com/richardkriesman/discord-logger/blob/master/server.js

What I'm tryna do is change the normal message to an embed.

Comment: @PeppaPapa basically you need to specify the channel where you want to send the embed, if you want to send the embed to the same channel then it can be done without `message.guild.channels.get(CHANNEL);`

Comment: It still won't send to the specified channel, or at all

Comment: have you created a channel named log?

Comment: Please read the answer properly, just copy the code and replace it with your messageDelete event. before running the code create a channel name log. when the channel is created successfully run the file.

Comment: I've replaced the code, buut at the top I've replaced the const for the channel name, did it break it? I'll add my version of the code as well if you care to look into it

Comment: no, it didn't break anything but make sure the channel name you have set exists in the discord server.

Comment: I've added the code, and also thanks for the help so far <3
Also yes the channel I have specified is an actual channel in the server

Comment: I have upvoted already, it just won't count it because of my rep. But do you know why it won't log it?

Comment: check the comment below your question. I would recommend you to start fresh. Just copy my whole code and run it @PeppaPapa

Comment: If the channel specified in the code is created? It is, and it doesn't crash, but It still won't work/send. Nvm sorry I see what you meant will look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202442/discussion-between-faizan-baig-and-peppa-papa).

Comment: @PeppaPapa lets discuss in chat